# NextJS lazy loading list of divs on scroll

Tags: node.js, next.js, lazy-loading

How would I go about loading a large amount of divs efficiently? My thought is to setup some kind of lazy loading where I load the divs at the end of the render and only when they are about to go into view. I was wondering how I would go about implementing this. I took a look at `react-loadable` but that seems to be more for importing components and lazy loading those.

My setup reads from a json list and maps through the data and outputs divs.

```
import list from './file.json'

return (
    {list.map((item) => (
        <div>{item}</div>
    ))}
)
```

Is there a way to implement `react-loadable` or this some similar library that can do what I need? Otherwise I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Check this lib, https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtual-scroller